# Django Ajax аутентификация

Tags: ajax, django, регистрация

Пробую Ajax аутентификацию.
После ввода данных прохожу аутентификацию

```
user = authenticate(request, username=usermame, password=password)
```

После логинюсь

```
auth.login(request, user)
```

Первый запрос делает все ок, пользователь аутентифицируется.

Если я делаю 2-й запрос на аутентификацию чтобы проверить что пользователь уже зарегистрировался, я получаю анонимный запрос

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
```

Тут объясняется,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50533472/python-django-autentication-anonymous-user-after-login
что после входа, все обращения Ajax должны сопровождаться передачей sessionid, как это сделать, подскажите, так ли это, как получать sessionid и передавать ее в data?

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Вы хотите получить данные авторизированного пользователя в Вашем шаблоне ?

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, я не пользуюсь шаблонами, весь фронтенд полностью на vue. Я регистрирую пользователя, отправляю данные на сервер, регистрирую, получаю в ответ подтверждение, пользователь свой, делаю отметку в vuex и иду дальше. Так вот, двумя методами, что указал выше я пользователя регистрирую, а вот во Vuе не пойму, как, закрепить инфу, может мне нужно сохранить sessionid и все запросы после регистрации посылать с ним?

Comment: Сейчас, после вроде бы удачной регистрации, я пробую заново пройти регистрации (пробую) и вижу информации о предшествующей регистрации нет

Comment: auth.login(request, user) принимает объекты HttpRequest и User, сохраняет идентификатор пользователя в сессии, используя соответствующий механизм. - эта процедура получается отлично. Когда я обращаюсь через Ajax с помощью VUE я в контроллере получаю Анонимного пользователя. Я полагаю должен в запрос Ajax включать параметр session и тогда Django должен обработать этот параметр и на входе в запросе будет определено от какого пользователя поступил этот запрос, подскажите это так?